# Apt-Offline downloads a full "upgrade" instead of only "update"

Tags: apt

I'm using a custom ISO of Xubuntu 16.04 updated (not upgraded) with packages from 2018. For ((reasons)) I can't install it, I depend on using it "Live" on a daily basis. And on top of that not always I have full internet connection. What matters is: instead of running "sudo apt-get update" everytime I reboot the system (which happens once a month roughly) I experimented with using "sudo apt offline". The problem is: from what I gather, when I perform a simple "apt-get update" it downloads a fairly small amount of data, no more than 20MB. When I used the "apt offline" tool, it seemed to download packages for a full distribution upgrade, it was amounting to 500MB when I cancelled it. Is there a way to only "update" package lists instead of performing a full "upgrade" of the system? I don't want to upgrade, I want to keep my software as is (intentionally outdated Firefox for example)

Comment: Please note Xubuntu 16.04 LTS (along with all flavors of Ubuntu from 16.04) is now EOL with only Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (desktop with unity, server, or kylin) still with full support. I would suggest replacing your ISO with Xubuntu 18.04 LTS   (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/  "*Maintenance updates are provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, Ubuntu Base, and Ubuntu Kylin. All the remaining flavours are supported for 3 years.*" - http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I made this customized ISO in the first place. But thanks for the insight. Still looking if "apt offline" has a way to be used just like "apt-get update" instead of "upgrade".